# Detecting ASP form submit no longer works

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following code on my ASP.Net pages.

```
$(window).submit(function () {
    prompt = false;
});
```

The point of this code is that if the user clicks a button on the page and does a postback for example then I set the prompt flag to false and do not prompt the user with "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

This worked fine up untill today now all of a sudden anytime the user clicks a button on the page he gets the prompt. I can't figure it out. This function is no longer getting called on any of the pages. Even if i revert the page back to when it worked still nothing.

So the problem is not on the page itself but somewhere else. Any ideas guys?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Probably something else broke your JS code. Check the error console.

Comment: So the problem was in the Site.Master

Chaning this:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

To:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

Resulted in the method never being executed. Problem is I don't know why even though the issue is fixed.

Comment: This might have your answer: http://www.zachleat.com/web/et-tu-x-ua-compatible/

Comment: @bfaveretto thanks, yes that helps explain it. Definitely unintuitive

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the Site.Master

Chaning this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

To:

Resulted in the method never being executed. Problem is I don't know why even though the issu